# The function of adding a '.' before resource name

Tags: java, classpath

```
        Class clazz = DBUtil.class; 
        inputStream = clazz.getResourceAsStream("./db.properties"); 
        properties.load(inputStream);
```

The relevant folder is `E:\JavaEE\day01\\bin\cn\itcast\path`

My task is to find the properties file. named `db.properties`. When I put the db.properties in the folder named bin, i can find it by the code`inputStream = clazz.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");`

But when I added a '.' before the '/', even if I put the properties in the most deepest folder of day01(`path folder`), I can still find them. Why?

Comment: What is your package name?

Comment: What folder is your classpath pointing to? What is the package of `DBUtil`? What do you mean by "most deepest folder of day01", given that the only visible `day01` is a second-level folder, and hence not that *deep*? Do you know what `.` means in a file path?

Comment: It's possible you may only be moving db.properties in the output folder and not in the src. If you only moved it in the output and then left it still at ./db.properties in src, it'll automatically move to the same location when it compiles and runs.

Comment: my project name is `day01`, `DBUtil's` package is `cn.itcast.path`,. Just because i didn't know the `.`means in a file path, so i asked for help. The reason why  i added a `.` before the `/` is i saw the jdk of `getResourceAsStream` method, but i couldn't understand what jdk means.@Andreas @Nghia Do

Comment: whant do you mean by " If you only moved it in the output and then left it still at ./db.properties in src". if "it" points to db.properties, what is "./db.properties" ? "./db.properties"  is only a code, not a file. @Jacob